# Facing issue Integrating microsoft MIP sdk in android App

Tags: java, android, cmake, microsoft-information-protection

I am trying to integrate microsoft MIP sdk in Android App , 
SDK has some header files and .so bin files along with that sdk has provided aria-android-java-sdk.aar file which is being used by one of the .so files using findClass API .
I am tried adding .so and header files and added aar file into build script but i am seeing below error .

```
  [     1586235339.801 32690: 317 E/void (anonymous namespace)::InitLogManager(JNIEnv *, jclass, jobject, const std::__ndk1Initializing Aria LogManager
2020-04-07 10:25:39.826 32690-317/com.sample.mipintegration A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.microsoft.applications.telemetry.core.InternalMgrImpl" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
2020-04-07 10:25:39.826 32690-317/com.sample.mipintegration A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]  at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
2020-04-07 10:25:39.826 32690-317/com.sample.mipintegration A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]  at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
2020-04-07 10:25:39.826 32690-317/com.sample.mipintegration A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]  at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Is there some way to add .so dependent aar file in android studio using cmake 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the InformationProtection.AAR, you should be able to call the function directly. Something like:

```
import com.microsoft.informationprotection.MipLibrary;

Func {
    MipLibrary.Init(getApplicationContext());
}
```

If you need to break apart the AAR you'll need to do something like this:

```
package com.microsoft.informationprotection;

import android.content.Context;

import java.lang.System;
import com.microsoft.applications.telemetry.core.InternalMgrImpl;
import com.microsoft.applications.telemetry.LogConfiguration;

public class MipLibrary {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("mip_core");
        System.loadLibrary("mip_protection_sdk");
        System.loadLibrary("mip_upe_sdk");
    }

    synchronized static public int Init(Context context) {
        if (sMipLibrary == null)
            sMipLibrary = new MipLibrary();
        if (sLogConfiguration == null) {
            sLogConfiguration = InternalMgrImpl.getConfig();
        }
        return sMipLibrary.Init(context.getClass(), context);
    }

    native int Init(Class<?> contextClass, Context context);

    static private MipLibrary sMipLibrary;
    static private LogConfiguration sLogConfiguration;
}
```

There's a JAR included in the AAR for the Protection SDK that is required as it contains info about the root CA used by the MIP service. This requirement will go away later this year.